# pronouns as subjects or objects

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I did a test in a session Test Your Grammar, in Word Power Made Easy by Lewis.

> 1) No one but (she, her) ever made a perfect score on the test
>
> 2) I can't remember (who, whom) it was.
>
> 3) Was it (she, her) you were talking about?
>
> 4) "It is I who (is, am) the only friend you've got", she told him pointedly.

The answers given by the book are 1) her, 2) who, 3) she, 4) am.

Of course I gave the other answers. But I don't understand why I am wrong. For example, in 1), we should choose a pronoun as a subject, not object. So I think 'she' is right; in 3), instead, we should choose a object, since the sentence means "was it that you were talking about her". So I think 'her' is right here.

What do you think?

Comment: Which sentence are you referring to?

Comment: The parentheses mean choosing of the two words, so the comma is not part of the sentence. Do you mean 'but' is a preposition here?

Comment: @Hue yes, and therefore, **no one but her** is true. I am a learner as you, I am not sure

Comment: In 1) "her" is not subject of the sentence (it's "no one but her") where her is object of the preposition "but". In 2) "who it was" is a subordinate interrogative clause with the pronoun as predicative complement of "be"; since complements of "be" are subjective case, then "who" is right. In 3) again, the pronoun is complement of "be" so subjective case "she" is correct (but note that "she" is very formal and most people ignore the rule and say "her". In 4) the subject of the relative clause is 1st person singular "I" and thus requires "am" ("is" is 3rd person sing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) No one but (she, her) ever made a perfect score on the test

After prepositions, you use object pronouns.  *But* is a preposition here.  The phrase *but her* is attached to *no one* (qualifying *no one* as a modifier) which is the subject of the sentence.  (If you have two subjects in a sentence they must be separated by *and* or *or*.)

> 3) Was it (she, her) you were talking about?

Note that the word order is flipped here because it's a question.  So the real sentence is *It was X*.

*To be* is one of a special category of verb called a *copular* that can be used to say two nouns/pronouns are the same.  What follows after these types of verbs is not really an object but a *complement*.  (If you can replace the "object" with a modifier and still have the sentence make sense, that's a good test to see if it's a complement or object.)

You can use subject pronouns in complements.  This is probably a rule of proper English that is often ignored in real speech, you would hear *Was it her* probably a lot more than *Was it she* unless someone was trying to sound formal.

Comment: In the parentheses of second last paragraph you mention **replace the "object" with a modifier**. Do you mean **replace "she" with an, for example, adjective** in this case? I don't think it makes sense to replace **she** with an adjective in this sentence.

Comment: Good point and you are right ... Thinknig about that more, that's not such a good heuristic.  Hopefully I did help illustrate the difference between complement and object a little, though.